# Why does the refrigerator shuts off when we are away?

Tags: refrigerator

Why did our refrigerator shut off (the circuit breaker it is connected to shut off) while we were away?  Samsung and others say we should shut the refrigerator off when we are away for more than 2 weeks.  I don't want to do that.  Why does it shut off on its own? Samsung implies that if the refrigerator did not shut off some damage would occur to the refrigerator.  Is this true.  I am not interested in energy saving (sorry).  Please just tell me why the refrigerator shuts off and if leaving on while we are way might damage it.

Comment: There might be a small possibility that not opening the door would increase frost levels, but two weeks should be minor.  Imagine this is a newer fridge full of electronics and other useless stuff.  Not using the fridge for two weeks is a good time to shut it off(if cleaned out), but a fridge itself should not make that decision.

Comment: You say "the circuit breaker it is connected to shut off".  That tells me the fridge didn't make the decision, so to speak.  Is it a simple circuit breaker, or more advanced one such as GFCI  or AFCI - does it have a test button?

Comment: Thank you.  The refrigerator is less than two years old. The warranty is 1 year on everything, 10 years on the compressor.  Samsung will make a service call but state I will charge $120 just for diagnosis.

Comment: It is not plug into the more advanced circuit-breaker plugs.  A main circuit breaker tripped.  No other circuit breakers tripped and the clocks were all running on time.  Neighbors in the building said there was no interruption of electric service.

Comment: Just to clarify: we were away for 10 weeks, not 2.

Comment: Is there any other appliance on the same circuit breaker, that could be guilty of tripping it? What is the amps rating of the breaker?

Comment: So, what do you  change when you go away? Otherwise the circuit breaker would trip when you are there...

Comment: Leaving food in your refrigerator and leaving it on while traveling *is perfectly reasonable*.  It's more environmental since wasting food has a carbon cost too. You don't need to defend a desire to not waste a freezer full of food.  However, StackExchange is not for grumbly rants.  So we need enough information to inform a solution.  Specifically what exactly is the type of breaker, photo prefered, and what other things are on the same circuit as the fridge i.e. what else lost power when the fridge did.

Comment: @crip659 if you think that stuff is useless, then next time my freezer becomes unusable due to an inch thick of accumulated ice, I'll call you to unload it and defrost it!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Freezers yes, but my 90s fridge has never been or needed defrosting.  Do have to open the door to check if the milk is low.

Comment: @crip659 my problem children are a couple of refrigerators that pre-date "frost-free" technology. Defrosting them is a monthly ordeal.  It's very anti-eco of me to even continue them in service, honestly!

Comment: Solar Mike: thanks for your help.  We didn't change anything and this is the only time this happened. Unless you advise otherwise, I am going to this, leave the refrigerator running while we are away next summer and hope for the best.  Either that or try to sell the thing and purchase a refrig with a "vacation mode" setting,

Comment: Never heard of a vacation mode on a refrigerator. HVAC? Sure - set it to 50-ish in the winter, 80-ish in the summer. But refrigerator? Only safe thing is 40/below - a.k.a., normal running - or off with the door open (because off with the door closed will let it grow stuff).

Answer (score 1):

The refrigerator did not shut off.  The breaker to the fridge was tripped.

There are no electronics made that will purposefully make a refrigerator overload a circuit.  So leave what Samsung thinks out of it.  There is nothing built-in to make this happen.

I also assume the breaker was in trip-free position, not in the off position due to your significant other deciding to turn it off to make Samsung happy.  The only thing that will make this happen is an overcurrent condition.  Your fridge does not have  a condition that will only occur when you aren't home.  Fridges run for months undisturbed in basements and garages across the world.  So you are going to have to wait for it to happen again and have it serviced if it does.